# Deriving Kretschmann scalar for Schwarzschild solution

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

I'm trying to derive  kretschmann scalar for schwarzschild solution, which is 
\begin{equation}
K=\frac{48M^{2}}{r^{6}}
\end{equation}
I know I have to compute $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$, but it seems like an almost impossible job to do directly, I have looked at some books and artciles but none of them does it explicitly. The most cited one is D'inverno(1992), but he just affirms that, he doesn't show it

Comment: I did this computation in one of my Master's projects. As far as I remember, I didn't find a fully detailed derivation anywhere back then. It's a fruitful exercise to do once in your life, though. It's not too hard; use all possible index symmetries.

Comment: I think this video will help you! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LkEaG48KgI

Answer (score 1):

It's just differentiation!

To minimize the amount of calculation, use (1) the fact that the metric is diagonal; (2) the fact that three of the metric components depend only on one coordinate, and the other depends only on two; (3) the symmetry of the Christoffel symbols; and (4) the multiple symmetries of the Riemann tensor.

You have to compute at most 40 of the 64 Christoffel symbols, and many of these 40 are zero. And you have to compute at most 21 (or even 20) of the 256 Riemann components. If you don't understand why, you need to learn more about the relevant symmetries.

The whole calculation should not take more than an hour by hand.

By the way, if you used the Cartan formalism it would be even easier, but your course may not have covered that way of calculating curvature.

And learning how to do it with a computer algebra program would also be instructive, for more complicated metrics like Kerr.

Comment: My estimate was too low. Allow a few hours.

Comment: you have to use symbolic manipulation program: I use Maple program to do this kind of calculation .

$K=R_{\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}\,R^{\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}\tag 1$

and

 $R^{\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}=\sum_{i=1}^4 g^{\kappa\,i}\,\sum_{j=1}^4 g^{\lambda\,j}\,\sum_{k=1}^4 g^{\mu\,k}\,\sum_{l=1}^4 g^{\nu\,l}\,R_{ijkl}\tag 2$

Where R is the Riemann curvature tensor and g the metric:

you don't have to write program code, it is quit easy to do the calculation for example equation (2).

Comment: for Kerr metric if you calculate the Kretschmann constant, you get this singularities?  ${r}^{8} \left( {r}^{2}+{a}^{2}+2\,mr{a}^{2} \right) ^{4} \left( -r+2\,
m \right) ^{4}
$ where m is the mass and a the angular momentum per unit mass.

Comment: @Eli There already exist Mathematica packages that compute the Kretschmann scalar for a chosen metric.

Comment: I don’t have this package.

Comment: To do it "properly" you should really start from the field equations, like this guy: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath655/kmath655.htm ;)